# How to pass a data from formType parent to formType child

Tags: forms, symfony, conditional-statements, entity-relationship

I have a form that takes place in several stages, including :

Step 1 : a simple form, based on an entity 1, which records a first part of the dataset.
Step 2 : a parent form (based on entity 1 in step 1), which implements a child form (based on entity 2) => CollectionType. The parent form ($builder) contains the data from step 1 but not the child form.

My obective is simple : my child form contains an ChoiceType, which will have to vary according to a given

My problem : pass to the child form a piece of data that the parent form has ($builder->getData()) to set an option condition for my ChoiceType.

I looked for solutions, but I did not find any result. So I think my problem is not a bug, but a bad approach on my part.

I tested :

```
//PARENT
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('wans', CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => WanDType::class,
                    'entry_options' => [
                        'label' => false,
                        'data' => $builder->getData() // <- here
                    ],
                ]);
    }

//ENFANT
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $ma_valeur = $builder->getData()->getValue(); //<- here
        if(in_array($ma_valeur, ['1'])) { //<- here
            $builder->add('profil', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    [...]
                ],
                'label' => false,
            ]);
        } else { //<- here
            $builder->add('profil', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    [...]
                ],
                'label' => false,
            ]);
        } //<- here
    }
```

*=> I get an error explaining that my data_class does not match my child form. In fact, the data_class of the parent form has replaced the data of the child form. The error proposes to give it null value but it causes other errors and symfony is less and less happy (logical, not a good practice in my opinion).*

=> I tried to use the $options. Symfony isn't happy because he refuses to add entries key=>values that he doesn't know at the origin.

=> I thought about making my condition in the parent form. But the condition can evolve over time, so creating a child form by type of conditions is not a good practice in my opinion.

=> I also thought about creating this field directly in the view. But that is not optimal either according to the evolutions.

=> I tested several things that are useless to mention here, for a negative result every time.

I strongly doubt that SensioLabs did not think of that kind of thing. I probably do not have to be far away, if anyone knows how to explain, it would be wonderful.

Thanks for your help :)

====================================================

EDIT test 1

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        dump($event->getForm()->getParent()->getData());
        die('ok');
    });
    die('ok2');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So. I did not find this very intuitive. Nothing explains how one must apprehend this technique in the context of a collection, when one wants to impact the entity contained by the collection.

So, we do not care about the concept of parent and child form. It is only to intervene on the form that is impacted by our modification (if it is the child, it will be in the formType child).

Basically, this gives this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add([....]); // without the fields I want to modulate.

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event){
        $wan = $event->getData();

        if(in_array($wan->getEquipment()->->getValue(),['1'])) {
            $event->getForm()->add('profil', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    [...]
                ],
                'label' => false,
            ]);
        } else {
            $event->getForm()->add('profil', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    [...]
                ],
                'label' => false,
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to do something like this can provide : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

with this you will be able to alter your form based on the provided data

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I had seen this documentation. Only she uses a simple form. Outside me, I want to impact a nested child form with what the parent form contains. I did not know how to apply these solutions to my needs: /

Comment: maybe with a `$event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()`

Comment: I see. But how do I pass the $event I build in EquipmentDType (parent) to WanDType (child)? The problem remains the same, right?

Comment: i think you only need to add the event inside the Child, no need to use it in the Parent form type

Comment: Ok. Well. In my child form (WanDType), I tested. I put in the main post, "EDIT test 1". I may be doing it wrong because it does not work. He shows me ok2 without showing me the rest.

Comment: I tested the methods proposed by the doc, without much success. On the other hand, enough suprise, I found a doc which speaks about it also, and which evokes the CollectionType. It helped me understand the doc :) By cons, I'm stuck. I understood how I could impact in the parent form, the CollectionType field itself. But I can not understand how I can impact the WanDType contained in the CollectionType.

Comment: I found! The doc is not very intuitive when you confront a CollectionType and you want to impact the Entity contained by the CollectionType. I put the result in the following post. Thank you very much Benoit for your suggestion :)